# Unable to publish customization from Customization Project Browser screen

Tags: acumatica

I am having a weird case where I am unable to publish customization from **Customization Project Browser**. Whenever I click on **Publish Current Project** menu item from **Publish** menu, it opens up Compilation immediate window with Publish Customization heading but then it just stuck there with no further process.

But, I can publish the same project from **Customization Projects Screen** where I select the Customization Project with checkbox and click on **Publish** action icon.

Currently, that's the workaround I am using to publish but is there any other way that I can do to fix this issue?

I have cleaned up ASP.NET Temporary Files and Acumatica's Apply Updates.

Thanks.

Comment: I have this issue as well, and have seen at least 1 other post about it.  Seems to be a bug, as best I can tell.  I'm on 20.112.0035.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's due to some update in .net framework.
the solution is to update acumaticaERP to the latest, or do some workaround.

1. publish from custom project form
2. edit web.config and add `<add key="aspnet:DisableAppPathModifier" value="false" />` to appSettings

https://community.acumatica.com/customization-and-development-72/after-the-installation-of-the-2020-10-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8-users-were-unable-to-publish-a-customization-project-from-the-customization-project-editor-3854

Comment: I opted to go with the workaround by adding <add key="aspnet:DisableAppPathModifier" value="false" /> in web.config. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the reason for this strange behavior, as well as the solution.  It happened to me as well.

Reason:  the w3wp process encounters an error during publishing.  The folder permissions for c:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\TemporaryAspFiles[yourAppName]
have been removed or deleted for the speficic windows account, which is used by the ERP, and the temporary sub-folders can't be created without create permission.  I can't see how it happened, but I noticed the strange behavior occurred after the last "major" windows update.  See the screenshot for the proof.
[image]

Solution:  re-apply the user account security for your application folder.  That is how I fixed the publish problem on my end.

Comment: This sounds promising, but it does not fix my issue, unless I am misunderstanding the exact steps you took.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, I also agree with @Deetz that it sounds like the only solution but unfortunately, it didn't work with me either. I gave Full Control not only to IIS_IUSRS but Everyone too to definitely make sure there is no permission Issue then restarted the IIS as well, but it didn't work.